# Azure Kubernetes version upgrade impact on client transactions

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, azure-aks

In a few weeks we will need to upgrade our AKS production cluster. We have tested everything already and are ready for the upgrade.
Except there is one issue, how will it impact user's session during upgrade?

To elaborate, our banking clients may be logged into the portal and carrying out transactions on the system. We will upgrade the system node pool first and that should not have an impact.

On our worker node pools, settings like: surge-option and min available pods have already been set. But **when the upgrade actually happens, what impact would it have on client's already logged into the application**.

I am tasked with documenting this so that the business is prepared.
can someone provide any inputs or suggestions?

Comment: Most of your questions can be answered here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/upgrade-cluster?tabs=azure-cli#upgrade-an-aks-cluster

> Ensure that any PodDisruptionBudgets (PDBs) allow for at least one pod replica to be moved at a time otherwise the drain/evict operation will fail. 

One pro tip, please go through the AKS release notes and refer to the version you are going to use, and pay special attention to changes. Sometimes there are few configurational changes required to make things work as they are. 
 Also app running should not use any deprecated APIs

Comment: @ishuar let me make the question even clearer. Suppose two clients are logged into our banking system when we plan to do upgrade. How can we ensure that when we do AKS upgrade that nodes/pods serving them when taken down would not impact their session?

Comment: To be honest to answer this someone needs the entire understanding of your current setup including application architectures and design ( if they support HA and so on ), but if I assume that your whole infra is set up correctly and only concerning the AKS upgrades, by default AKS  upgrade process add a new buffer node and then cordon nodes as per max surge and get the updates once the node/s are drained properly. In ideal situations there is no downtime however I can not comment on it in your case.